# How to set value to a input tag without an Id or class

Tags: vb.net

I want to input the value into a input field from a web browser on a vb form.
But the problem is the tag does not have an Id or Class name

```
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="50" style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom: 3px;width: 200px;" readonly="">
```

Similarly for password field

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom: 3px;width: 200px;" maxlength="60" readonly="">
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Both seem to have a name attribute. Can't you use that?

Comment: Why would you not put an `id` attribute on these? If you need to access these on the client-side, the `id` would be the fastest selector. If you need to access them on the server, then alongside an ID, you will need a `runas="server"` attribute too.